# How to integrate UIkit with Aurelia

Tags: uikit, aurelia, getuikit

How do I integrate UIkit 3 with Aurelia in an aurelia-cli project. What are the changes necessary in aurelia.json to achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

right now the uikit3 build tool generates an anonymous module which can't be used with the cli, I submitted a pull request to remedy that, until its fixed you can use the cdn version.